# PropertyPath and PathParameters in Constructor

Tags: wpf, binding

I was trying to bind my DataGrid columns to a list where the item for a column could be retrieved using an indexer. The indexer type is DateTime.

I am creating the DataGrid columns using code and wanted to create a binding to retrieve the value from the list. In XAML the path would be written as:

{ Binding Path=Values[01/01/2011] }

But since I am doing it in code behind I need to define the path using a PropertyPath, like so:

```
new Binding{
    Path = new PropertyPath("Values[01/01/2011]")
}
```

There is another overload for the constructor that takes a path and an array of parameters. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587924.aspx) the parameters are used for indexers. But when I write my binding as

```
new Binding {
    Path = new PropertyPath("Values", new DateTime(2011, 01, 01))
}
```

the binding cannot resolve the path. Fair enough, I'm not stating that it should look for an indexer. But if I write it as:

new Binding{
    Path = new PropertyPath("Values[]", new DateTime(2011, 01, 01))
}

then DateTime.MinValue is passed to the indexer.

Can someone explain to me how I use the PathParameters in the constructor and how I can bind to indexers without having to do a ToString on my value in the actual path?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertypath.path.aspx) article, you'd need to include "(0)" to indicate where the parameter should be placed. So the following should work:

```
new Binding {
    Path = new PropertyPath("Values[(0)]", new DateTime(2011, 01, 01))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, was beginning to think there was no answer.